# RobotFrameWork- some Libraries are not imported

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to RobotFramework. I installed vs code with robocorp extensions.
i also installed several libraries like:

- seleniumlibrary
- screencaplibrary
- jsonlibrary

the issue is that some libraries are not imported as expected, like:

- screencaplibrary
- jsonlibrary

However,

- seleniumlibrary

imported without errors
what am i doing wrong?

see screenshot attached:

[screencaplibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1eGs.png)
[jsonlibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxqQ0.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you haven't set your pythonpath for robotframework.

To do this go to the Robot Framework Language Server extension and go to extension settings.

In there you'll find: Robot > Language-server: Python
[image]

and: Robot > Python: Executable
[image]

Set both of them to your python.exe path and restart vsc.

Answer (score 1):

For Pycharm, please go to `languages & frameworks` in settings and update/add the python path for the field `Language Server Python`.

[image]

In order to get these options within the `languages & frameworks`-section, you will need to have the `Robot Framework Language Server` plugin installed.

- Link to plugin: [Robot Framework Language Server](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16086-robot-framework-language-server)