# Error generating libspec: When trying to Import python libraries into Robot Framework project using libraries.resouce file

Tags: python, robotframework

```
IDE: VSCode 
Python 3.10 + RobotFramework 5.0.1 
vscode extension: Robot Framework Language server 0.47.2
```

Folder structure:

[image]

In libraries.resource file i am calling the dbutils library as:

```
Libraries     ./libraries/Utilities/utils.py
```

In my utils.py file, i am importing the file dbutils.py as:

```
from libraries.DBUtilities.dbutils import dbutils

class utils():
      def __init__(self):
          self.ut = dbutils()
```

With this setup, the robotframework language server throws the error as below:

```
Unresolved library: ../libraries/Utilities/utils.py
Error generating libspec:
Importing library 'utils' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
Consider adding the needed paths to the "robot.pythonpath" setting
and calling the "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" action.robotframework
```

I have tried,

- use Import instead of from
- use try: and except:
- added the libraries into the vscode workspace file under "robot.pythonpath" section
- applied "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" from the vscode command pallete

Edit 1:

```
project workspace file has the following settings:

"robot.pythonpath": ["${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python.exe", "${workspaceFolder}/libraries"],
    "robot.language-server.python": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python.exe",
    "robot.python.executable": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python.exe",
```

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71931370/robotframework-some-libraries-are-not-imported/72324894#72324894

Comment: Pradeep, can you confirm you have tried the answer i linked above? I'm confident it could fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Ruben, it didn't work for me. I have these settings changed in the project workspace file.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct python path? Because i'm using the exact same environment as you and have set it up on different machines at my workplace. If you don't know your python path you can open a cmd and type: 'python.exe where' this will return your path to python.exe. Make sure you also set them in the extension settings as shown in the linked answer above. Only in workspace file may not be enough.

Comment: Python virtual environment is part of my project and all the libraries and python executable instance is part of it. All other code execution works fine with the same path.

Comment: I totally have same issue right now. And adding @Ruben solutionto my robot settings didnt solve my problem. I am still getting error on python importing libraries on vscode. Have you solved this issue pradeep ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Ruben works, but in your case I guess you have to set your environment path in the fields, to get that path simply use this command:

```
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your robot.pythonpath settings in code-workspace is wrong, the usage is to put paths where to find your own python implementation, not the python executable. So it shall be only :

```
"robot.pythonpath": ["${workspaceFolder}/libraries"]
```

In your robot framework, you shall include your utils.py file like this to be aligned with indication of your robot python path :

```
Libraries     Utilities/utils.py
```

I suppose you have also pylance extension to analyse python file, you need to add the setting :

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/libraries"]
```

You could also do the other way while it is consistent ...:

```
"robot.pythonpath": ["${workspaceFolder}"]

 Libraries     libraries/Utilities/utils.py
```

Regarding "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" from the vscode command pallete, there is a bug in the extension, it doesn not re-apply the workspace settings !
You need to Close the workspace and reopen ths worspace to re-apply the settings of robot.pythonpath.

Carefully filling the paths of python libraries in robot.pythonpath and being aware that the Clear caches clear also robot.pythonpath make the things works perfectly for me.